# Windows Media Foundation: getting AAC decoded data

Tags: c++, audio, aac, ms-media-foundation, data-extraction

I want to use **Windows Media Foundation** to get the audio data of an AAC-encoded file. I figured out that the right way is to declare an IMFSample* where the single sample of the audio will be kept. In VS2015 I see that this class has a method getDouble(), but there is nothing about it in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms702192(v=vs.85).aspx).

Here is the part of example I am trying to do:

```
    IMFSample *pSample(NULL);

    hr = m_pReader->ReadSample(
        MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM, // [in] DWORD dwStreamIndex,
        0,                                   // [in] DWORD dwControlFlags,
        NULL,                                // [out] DWORD *pdwActualStreamIndex,
        &dwFlags,                            // [out] DWORD *pdwStreamFlags,
        &timestamp,                          // [out] LONGLONG *pllTimestamp,
        &pSample);                           // [out] IMFSample **ppSample
```

The last argument **pSample** is what I want.

Now, I want to get double, float or byte pointer to the current **decoded** sample data.

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert the sample to a buffer:

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> mediaBuffer;
sample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&mediaBuffer)
```

Then lock the buffer to get a pointer to its internals:

```
BYTE *audioData = nullptr;
DWORD sampleBufferLength = 0;
mediaBuffer->Lock(&audioData, nullptr, &sampleBufferLength);
// use audioData...
mediaBuffer->Unlock();
```

To specify what the format of the data is returned to you use `SetCurrentMediaType` on your reader (do this once at the beginning)

```
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IMFMediaType> pPartialType;
    MFCreateMediaType(&pPartialType);
    pPartialType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio);
    pPartialType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_Float);
    reader->SetCurrentMediaType(
        (DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM,
        NULL, pPartialType.Get());
```

And please use smart pointers everywhere with MF or you'll enter a world of pain. `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<XXX>` is your friend! I've missed out checking the HRESULTs in this example code but you'll definitely want to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike. I got another question. The data we will get from this is the non-decoded right?

Comment: @mbaros This will be the decoded data - a list of floats [in the range 0 to 1.0] representing the raw samples.